# Converting a program that takes in a .txt file and modifying to functions

Tags: python, function

Completely stuck on functions....

I have a .txt file:

```
Bronson 90 85 75 76 
Conor 90 90 90 90
Austyn 50 55 32 75
Mark 96 95 85 85
Anthony 85 85 85 85
```

And I'm trying to take this code (below). And turn it into functions to produce the same output:

```
with open(argv[1]) as f:
     names = []
     for line in f:
        names.append(line.split()[0])
        print('\nNames of students who have written tests:')
        print(*sorted(names), sep=' ')

# prompt user to input which student you want to view
      name = input('Enter name of student whose test results '
                     'you wish to see: ')
      if name not in names:
          print('\nNo test data found for ', name)
          input("Press Enter to continue ...")
      else:
          name_print = "\nSummary of Test Results for " + name

# print test scores of the student selected
      with open(argv[1]) as f:
          for line in f:
              parts = line.split()
              if parts[0] == name:
                  print(name_print)
                  print('=' * ((len(name_print)) - 1))
                  test_scores = ' '.join(parts[1:])
                  print('Test scores: ', end=' ')
                  print(test_scores)
```

Currently outputs:

```
Names of students who have written tests:
Anthony Austyn Bronson Conor Mark
Enter name of student whose test results you wish to see: Anthony

Summary of Test Results for Anthony
===================================
Test scores:  85 85 85 85
Number of tests written ..................  4
```

I want to make it run on one main() module using `process_marks(f)`:

```
from functions import process_marks 

def main():
    try:
        f = open(argv[1])
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nFile ", argv[1], "is not available")
        exit()
    process_marks(f). #The program essentially runs in this function with help from helpers
    f.close()

main()
```

This is what I currently have:

```
def process_marks(f):
        names = []
        for line in f:
            names.append(line.split()[0])
        print('\nNames of students who have written tests:')
        names = sorted(names)
        print(*names, sep=' ')
        name = input('Enter name of student whose test results '
                     'you wish to see: ')
        check_name(name, names)
        print_grades(name, line)

def check_name(name, names):
    if name not in names:
        print('\nNo test data found for ', name)
        input("Press Enter to continue ...")
    else:
        name_print = "\nSummary of Test Results for " + name
        print(name_print)
        print('=' * ((len(name_print)) - 1))

def print_grades(name, line):
    test_scores = ' '.join(line[1:])
    print('Test scores: ', end=' ')
    print(test_scores)
```

This is what outputs using above code:

```
Names of students who have written tests:
Anthony Austyn Bronson Conor Mark
Enter name of student whose test results you wish to see: Mark

Summary of Test Results for Mark
================================
Test scores:  n t h o n y   8 5   8 5   8 5   8 5
```

I don't want to go to far away from the current code I have (i want to use lists etc because id like to eventually include averages, max, min etc. However, I have been grinding over this for a while having obvious problems getting the code to access the line that corresponds to the name.

Comment: The problem is in the function process_marks. You pass line to the function print_grades , when its value equals the last row of the txt file.

Comment: Please don't post the same question in different variations many times. You have already asked the exact question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468330/creating-a-function-to-process-through-a-txt-file-of-student-grades/60468700#60468700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method-breakdown is a bit off.

For example this line:

```
print_grades(name, line)
```

Will use the last value of `line` from the for loop above. Which will always be `"Anthony"`

You can try to pass the values from method to method as below:

```
from sys import argv


def get_names(my_file):
    names = []
    for line in my_file:
        names.append(line.split()[0])
        print('\nNames of students who have written tests:')
        print(*sorted(names), sep=' ')
    return names


def get_and_check_name(names):
    name = input('Enter name of student whose test results '
                 'you wish to see: ')
    if name not in names:
        print('\nNo test data found for ', name)
        input("Press Enter to continue ...")
    else:
        name_print = "\nSummary of Test Results for " + name
        return name, name_print


def print_scores(f, name, name_print):
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        if parts[0] == name:
            print(name_print)
            print('=' * ((len(name_print)) - 1))
            test_scores = ' '.join(parts[1:])
            print('Test scores: ', end=' ')
            print(test_scores)


def process_marks(f):
    While True:
        names = get_names(f)
        name, name_print = get_and_check_name(names)
        f.seek(0)
        print_scores(f, name, name_print)
        yes_no = input('\nDo again for another student?')
        if yes_no == 'n':
            break
        continue 

with open(argv[1]) as f:
    process_marks(f)
```

Comment: Works for me. Please make sure you use the code I provided in the answer.

Comment: I feel like i'm very close.... I don't know if it would affect but I'm importing this functions module into a main() like in my original post. in the main() its being called with a try: f = open(argv[1]

Comment: in print_scores() for line in f: nameError: name 'f' is not defined. The program does everything else up until print_scores

Comment: Fixed, do check

Comment: This is great. So basically where i was going wrong was that i wasnt taking the values from previous methods and passing them into the next correctly ??

Comment: Yeah. The methods were using values from the outer scope which may cause unexpected bahaviour.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. One more quick question. I want to wrap the whole thing in a While True loop. So it loops through until user enters n. This is what i have (which loops through as wanted. However, it doesn't take in the list of names the second time through. See edit

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response